# Getting Started With TLS In SMTP Using Winsock & C?

Tags: c, sockets, email, smtp, winsock2

I'm writing a very raw SMTP client in C. I understand basic functionality of sockets using Winsock / Linux and made my client successfully talk to Google's SMTP servers.

However I'm a newbie when it comes to TLS / SSL. After reading some protocol documentation of SMTP, I noticed after I send the "STARTTLS" command, I need to negotiate the server of a encrypted connection and start sending packets in TLS. I see the MSDN doc talk about TLS, but doesn't really give any examples, or perhaps I'm missing the point all together.

1. "Negotiate" how does that happen with the client and server when choosing an encryption?
2. How do I start sending packets in TLS using Winsock?

I'm more of a learn by example type of guy, and I already spent some time searching around, but nothing as far as I can tell has a good example of doing this. Which is why I'm asking here hopping someone can point me in the right direction.

### smtp.h

```
#ifndef SMTP_H
#define SMTP_H

#include <winsock2.h>

#define MAX_SMTP_RECIVE_BUFFER_SIZE 4096
#define SMTP_SEPERATOR "\r\n"

struct emailPacket {
    char* fromHeader;
    char* toHeader;
    char* subjectHeader;
    char* message;
    char* contentType;
};

int setupWinsock();
void cleanupWinsock();
struct emailPacket* emailOpen(const char* fromHeader, const char* toHeader);
int emailSetMessage(const char* message, const char* contentType, struct emailPacket* packet);
int emailSetSubject(const char* subject, struct emailPacket* packet);
int emailSendPacket(const char* smtpHost, const char* smtpUsername, const char* smtpPassword, unsigned int port, struct emailPacket* packet);
void emailClose(struct emailPacket* packet);
int sendSMTPPacket(SOCKET socket, const char* data);
int recvNULLSMTPPacket(SOCKET socket);

#endif
```

### smtp.c

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include "smtp.h"

#include <winsock2.h>


int setupWinsock()
{
     WSADATA wsa;
     if (WSAStartup(MAKEWORD(2,2),&wsa) != 0)
     {
        return 0;
     }

     return 1;
}

void cleanupWinsock()
{
    WSACleanup();
}

struct emailPacket* emailOpen(const char* fromHeader, const char* toHeader)
{
    struct emailPacket* packet = malloc(sizeof(struct emailPacket));

    if(!packet)
        return NULL;

    size_t fromHeaderLength = sizeof(char) * strlen(fromHeader) + 1;
    packet->fromHeader = malloc(fromHeaderLength);

    if(!packet->fromHeader)
    {
        free(packet);
        return NULL;
    }

    size_t toHeaderLength = sizeof(char) * strlen(toHeader) + 1;
    packet->toHeader = malloc(toHeaderLength);

    if(!packet->toHeader)
    {
        free(packet);
        return NULL;
    }

    // Set char arrays to 0.
    memset(packet->fromHeader, 0, fromHeaderLength);
    memset(packet->toHeader, 0, toHeaderLength);

    // If everything is good copy string to packet buffer.
    strcpy(packet->fromHeader, fromHeader);
    strcpy(packet->toHeader, toHeader);

    return packet;
}

int emailSetMessage(const char* message, struct emailPacket* packet)
{
    if(!packet)
        return 0;

    size_t messageLength = sizeof(char) * strlen(message) + 1;
    packet->message = malloc(messageLength);

    if(!packet->message)
        return 0;

    memset(packet->message, 0, messageLength);
    strcpy(packet->message, message);
    return messageLength;
}

int emailSetSubject(const char* subject, struct emailPacket* packet)
{
    if(!packet)
        return 0;

    size_t subjectLength = sizeof(char) * strlen(subject) + 1;
    packet->subjectHeader = malloc(subjectLength);

    if(!packet->subjectHeader)
        return 0;

    memset(packet->subjectHeader, 0, subjectLength);
    strcpy(packet->subjectHeader, subject);
    return subjectLength;
}

int emailSendPacket(const char* smtpHost, const char* smtpUsername, const char* smtpPassword, unsigned int port, struct emailPacket* packet)
{
    SOCKET connection;

    // Create our sock connection.
    if((connection = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0)) == INVALID_SOCKET)
    {
        printError("Could not create socket! : %d", WSAGetLastError());
        return 0;
    }

    struct hostent* convertedHost = gethostbyname(smtpHost);
    struct sockaddr_in server;

    memcpy(&server.sin_addr, convertedHost->h_addr_list[0], convertedHost->h_length);
    server.sin_family = AF_INET;
    server.sin_port = htons( port );

    // Connect to the SMTP server!
    if (connect(connection , (struct sockaddr *)&server , sizeof(server)) < 0)
    {
        printError("Failed connecting to SMTP server! : %d", WSAGetLastError());
        return 0;
    }

    printMessage("Established connection to %s! Telling SMTP whats going to happen.", smtpHost);

    char* tempBuffer[MAX_SMTP_RECIVE_BUFFER_SIZE];

    // Recive the inital response from the server.
    recvNULLSMTPPacket(connection);

    sprintf(tempBuffer, "EHLO %s%s", smtpHost, SMTP_SEPERATOR);
    sendSMTPPacket(connection, tempBuffer);
    recvNULLSMTPPacket(connection);

    sprintf(tempBuffer, "STARTTLS%s", SMTP_SEPERATOR);
    sendSMTPPacket(connection, tempBuffer);
    recvNULLSMTPPacket(connection);

    // send MAIL FROM: <sender@mydomain.com>
    sprintf(tempBuffer, "MAIL FROM:<%s>%s", packet->fromHeader, SMTP_SEPERATOR);
    sendSMTPPacket(connection, tempBuffer);
    recvNULLSMTPPacket(connection);

    // send RCPT TO: <receiver@domain.com>
    // repeat for each to-address
    sprintf(tempBuffer, "RCPT TO:<%s>%s", packet->toHeader, SMTP_SEPERATOR);
    sendSMTPPacket(connection, tempBuffer);
    recvNULLSMTPPacket(connection);

    printMessage("Sending SMTP DATA!", smtpHost);

    // send DATA
    sprintf(tempBuffer, "DATA%s", SMTP_SEPERATOR);
    sendSMTPPacket(connection, tempBuffer);
    recvNULLSMTPPacket(connection);

    // send Subject
    sprintf(tempBuffer, "Subject: %s\n", packet->subjectHeader);
    sendSMTPPacket(connection, tempBuffer);

    // send From and To
    sprintf(tempBuffer, "From: %s\n", packet->fromHeader);
    sendSMTPPacket(connection, tempBuffer);

    // send From and To
    sprintf(tempBuffer, "To: %s\n\n", packet->toHeader);
    sendSMTPPacket(connection, tempBuffer);

    // send Content-Type
    sprintf(tempBuffer, "Content-Type: text/plain; charset=\"ISO-8859-1\"\n");
    sendSMTPPacket(connection, tempBuffer);

    // prepare the string that will be sent as message body
    sendSMTPPacket(connection, packet->message);

    // send blank line and a period to end data transmission
    sprintf(tempBuffer, "%s.%s", SMTP_SEPERATOR, SMTP_SEPERATOR);
    sendSMTPPacket(connection, tempBuffer);
    recvNULLSMTPPacket(connection);

    // Send QUIT
    sprintf(tempBuffer, "QUIT%s", SMTP_SEPERATOR);
    sendSMTPPacket(connection, tempBuffer);
    recvNULLSMTPPacket(connection);

    closesocket(connection);

    if(DEBUG)
    {
        printMessage(">>>>> PRINTING SMTP MESSAGE <<<<<");
        printMessage(">>>>> END <<<<<");
    }

    return 0;
}

void emailClose(struct emailPacket* packet)
{
    if(packet)
    {
        free(packet);
        packet = NULL;
    }
}

int sendSMTPPacket(SOCKET socket, const char* data)
{
    const char* conBuffer = data;
    int bytesLeft = strlen(conBuffer);
    int bytesSent = 0;

    while(bytesLeft > 0)
    {
        bytesSent = send(socket, conBuffer, bytesLeft, 0);

        if(!bytesSent)
        {
            return bytesSent;
        }

        bytesLeft -= bytesSent;
        conBuffer += bytesSent;
    }

    return bytesSent;
}

int recvNULLSMTPPacket(SOCKET socket)
{
    char buffer[250];
    int bytesRecived = recv(socket, buffer, 250, 0);

    printMessage("%s", buffer);
    return bytesRecived;
}
```

### somewhereInMain

```
if(!setupWinsock())
    return;

struct emailPacket* email = emailOpen(CONTACT_EMAIL, CONTACT_EMAIL);

if(!email)
    return;

emailSetSubject("Host Information", email);
emailSetMessage("Hello, World!", email);
emailSendPacket(SMTP_SERVER, CONTACT_EMAIL, "password", SMTP_SERVER_PORT, email);
emailClose(email);

cleanupWinsock();
```

P.S I know some stuff I posted could be a lot better. i.e making sendSMTPPacket simply accept arguments like sprintf, again this is a very raw and dirty implementation atm.

Comment: The best (and safest) way to handle this is to use an encryption library that handles TLS for you, like Microsoft's [SChannel](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa380123.aspx), or *maybe* WinSock's [Secure Socket Extensions](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb394815.aspx) (I've never used that, though), or a third-party library like [OpenSSL](https://openssl.org/). Otherwise, stop implementing SMTP manually and use a pre-made SMTP library instead. For instance, [libcurl](https://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/) supports SMTP with and without TLS.

Comment: I'll look more into Microsoft Crypto. I would be open to a SMTP lib, but I need something extremely lightweight, and I know this isn't the type of forum to be asking around that type of question. Not sure why you didn't reply as a answer, would have +1 it. ;)